# std::make_move_iterator vs. std::move for vector concatenation

Tags: c++

(This is about the `std::move` from `<algorithm>`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move)

AFAIK, there are two common ways to move the content of one vector to the end of another.

First:

```cpp
std::vector<T> dst, src;
...
dst.insert(dst.end(),
           std::make_move_iterator(src.begin()),
           std::make_move_iterator(src.end()));
```

Second:

```cpp
std::vector<T> dst, src;
...
std::move(src.begin(),
          src.end(),
          std::back_inserter(dst));
```

Are these both idiomatic ways to do concatenation? If so, is there any difference in terms of semantics?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either should get the job done, but there is a subtle difference. When you use `insert`, the vector has the chance to allocate memory enough to hold all elements in one allocation. When you use `back_inserter`, that's the equivalent of multiple `push_back`s which may do multiple allocations and moves.

Comment: I see, so if I reserve before `move`ing with `back_inserter`, it should be the same?

Comment: @ZizhengTai yes, they they would be similar, but I'd use insert and let the compiler decide.

Comment: I put both functions in wrappers and put them in Godbolt. I found that `move`ing with `back_inserter`, has a loop in the hot-path. When I brought them both into Quick-Bench, found that even on int-vectors of size 7, that the `move`+`back_inserter` is about twice as slow. While they both yield the same results, the `insert` is the better way to go.

Comment: @AlexShirley I believe Scott Meyers has an item on this in one of his books suggesting to prefer `insert` over `back_inserter`. That might be a good read for OP

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili I scoured my collection and sure enough Scott mentions it in Effective STL - specifically in the section titled "Prefer Range Member Functions to their single element counterparts."